# Firebase store data into root directory

Tags: swift, firebase

Im trying to store data into the root which mean that im not using any child path what is the correct way to do this I want to store "var Value". Thank you in advance.

my JSon

[image: my Json]

my code

```
paymentStatus == "submitted_for_settlement"{
                    let paidStatus = [
                        "status":"paid",
                        "isReceiverPaid": false as AnyObject,
                        "totalPaid":amount,
                        "senderFee":1.5,
                        "senderRating":"notSet",
                        "receiverRating":"notSet",
                        "DateFundsWillRelease":"11/2/2017"

                ] as NSDictionary


let frontEnd = ["posts/\(self.postId!)/paidPostStatus":paidStatus]

let backEnd = ["userSubmitted/postPaymentMade":paidStatus]

let values = [
              "frontEnd":frontEnd,
              "backEnd":backEnd
             ]

FIRDatabase.database().reference().updateChildValues(values, 
                                   withCompletionBlock: {_,_ in

})
```

Comment: Didn't understand what you want.

Comment: There are a number of potential coding errors; a dangling bracket {, using == as assignment (?) and you may want to consider moving away from NSDictionary and make the code more Swifty using Dictionary. Also please post JSON structures as text, not images. Finally, the structure you have posted matches the code in the question so it's unclear what's being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is really:

> Im trying to store data into the root

then then answer is

```
let parentNodeRef = rootRef.child("my_parent_node")
parentNodeRef.setValue("my value")
```

which will result in

```
your_root
 my_parent_node: "my value"
```

If you truly mean no child nodes then this is the answer (PLEASE don't do this as it will wipe everything in the node)

```
rootRef.setValue("Don't do this")
```

which gives you a parent with no child values

```
your_root: "Don't do this"
```